# NPC Guildmaster to oppose a high-level thief

Tags: adnd-1e, thief

In AD&D 1st edition a high-level thief is not allowed to build a stronghold or castle like a high-level fighter, but he/she can build/buy a tower or mansion.  This will then put them in conflict with the local Thieve's Guild and a turf war then ensues.

Are there any good stock NPCs to use for the local Master Thief and his associated guild henchmen?

I'm looking for both stats and personality.  Maybe also some supporting background info; number/type of henchmen, that kind of thing.

Comment: I don't think the title of this question matches what you're really looking for, or else you need to rephrase the last line. Do you need a stronghold, some NPCs or both?

Comment: Great edit on the title. Perfectly clear now.

Comment: Could you clarify the question to say whether you're looking for appropriate NPC stats or for suitable NPC personalities? Or both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend rolling up a 9th to 12th level thief and using the high level adventuring party chart in the Dungeon Master Guide to equip him. Remember that he part of hierarchy and that he survived X years and Y adventures to get to that position. If he been established for any amount of time there going to be a little society of thieves with a hierarchy.

What I would do is create this background and introduce the players to through the normal course of the campaign. Realize that now the character is "name" level he is developing a reputation and people will naturally flock to him. That what the stronghold rule in AD&D about. It isn't about that you can't establish anything before 9th level but rather when you do reach 9th level your reputation is known.

Of course with this comes new problems. Ones that his adventuring career may not prepare him for. And it will draw the attention of other like him (which you already noted). The game becomes more about the society and culture in which all of them exist. Society and culture will form the battlefield on which these two fight. The focus will not the high level view of Kings and Princes but the underbelly of society.

For two concrete (and free) example I posted two writeup from my long running campaign. The [Brotherhood of the Lion](http://wilderlands.batintheattic.com/brotherhoodlion.html) and the [Beggar's Guild](http://wilderlands.batintheattic.com/beggarsguild.html). The Brotherhood is a resistance group several generations after the conquest of City-State. The Beggars are dishonored descendants of the conquerors.

I also recommend tracking down any of the old [Thieves Guild Supplement from Gamelords](http://www.diffworlds.com/gamelords_thieves_guild.htm). What particularly valuable are the dozens of scenarios for thieves they include in each book.

Answer (score 1):

The AD&D [Lankhmar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lankhmar_%E2%80%93_City_of_Adventure) setting book has an wide and assorted variety of thief and thief related NPCs.

The setting details the world of Fafhrd and the Gray Mouser, if you're not familiar with it,  it's something of a mixture of high fantasy and urban noir - a bit of Sin City (movie or comic) in a fantasy world, and the thieves guild and its interactions with player characters are central to the setting.