# What does a Thieves Guild turf war look like?

Tags: adnd-1e, thief

Related to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4015/stronghold-for-a-high-level-thief), what is actually involved in a turf war between a high-level thief character and the local Thieves Guild?

I assume that Assassins are involved at some point.  What other types of characters or scenarios would occur?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic gist is that my buddies are going to kill or beat the crap out of your buddies with the minimum amount of attention from the authorities. This continues until you submit or die. And if you are the leader likely you will die no matter what and your flunkies will be run by a new lieutenant appointed by me.

There is a lot more stupidity going on with turf wars. If they were that smart probably they wouldn't be thieves in a turf war in the first place. The exception is somebody younger who is just starting out. Note this is a general observation that if you look at the everybody involved they are not as organized, not as smart, etc., etc. as say the nobles, merchants, and so on.

However the dividing line between what the thieves do and the rest of medieval/fantasy society does is inches. A war between two barons can have all the elements of a turf war.

What really counts is loyalty to your buddies. It will be the defining element of the conflict. It will start for any number of reasons, greed, lust, or plain stupidity. But it will be fueled by revenge and the desire not to fail in front your peers.

It's also about relative status. Conflicts that are not to the death are fought until one side acknowledges, by whatever custom dictates, the other is better/bigger/badder/boss.

Plus since we are dealing with the criminal element the relationships within and between the faction are distorted, twisted or plain abusive in any number of ways. For example,  part of a lieutenant's loyalty to his boss may involve the fact his boss supplies his girlfriend with Lotus Powder (a drug) for free. This connection can be exploited by the other side or be a source of a conflict.

Your character finds this out and destroys their supply of Lotus Powder, making it look like the Boss' screw-up. Now the Lieutenant is unhappy and you come along and offer him an alternative supply for a few "favors".

The City-State of the Invincible Overlord has been one of the centerpieces of my campaign and I run several campaigns where thieves and the criminal class were the focus.

One of the most memorable was when two of my players played a pair of brothers. Thugs for the most part. They were given a job and fed inaccurate information. It got screwed up and they got blamed for it as well as not getting paid. They went chaotic and started with their boss and killed him, then killed their boss' boss and so on, working their way up the hierarchy. They were given some information about the Prince of the Thieves Guild. When they followed up they found themselves in a trap and were killed.

The players weren't upset as they acknowledge they shouldn't have trusted the contact as much as they did. About midway through their killing spree one of the rival Princes, through intermediaries, started feeding them information and using the chaos they caused to advance his position. When their usefulness ended he laid the trap and killed them.

Comment: I've always thought a great inspiration for how the thieves are behaving can be drawn from the actions of the youths (male) in Romeo and Juliet.

Comment: That is an excellent example.

Comment: Great advice and excellent story +1

Answer (score 3):

Every fire needs a spark to start it.  Have a slight (real or imagined) start the plot-line.  Maybe the old and established Thieves Guild does not get the contract to steal the widget.  Maybe the Upstarts decide to prove their skills by stealing the flag off of the roof of the thieves guild.

At each step of the way, there's going to be many opportunities to escalate or de-escalate the conflict.  For the war to happen, concentrate each side "one upping" the other.  Sooner or later, there will be wholesale thieving going on between them.  And sooner or later, Agent X will be caught in Guild Y and get killed for it.

This stage should mostly be assassins or thieves killing as stealthily as possible.  My guess is that one of these stealth-kills goes sour, and the assassin barely makes it out of the guild headquarters.  In trying to escape, they chase him to his hideout, and somewhere the guard sees this happen.  You now have an open conflict.

Fast forwarding to the end of the conflict, either one of the guilds gets wiped out (or nearly so), or one of the guilds decides they are in over their heads, and calls for a peace.  The details of the peace/truce can make a LARGE number of plot-seeds (guilds split the city, but start getting jobs in my side that takes me to your side, how does that get handled; etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The thieve's guild would probably have contacts with local law enforcement, double agents probably. What could happen is one side would steal something from a prominent figure, and one of the snitches would report that the character had done it. Now the character is the focus of an investigation, and has acquired the enemy of a wealthy and powerful NPC.

The guild would also try to poison the well for the character, pressuring fences to not take on stolen goods, and just generally shutting down the black market. A few would decide to work with whomever gets them money, but then assassins would be sent out to take care of them. It's not just an issue of taking out the person who is at the top, but also making it so that nobody wants to switch allegiances.

The character would have to find a way to fight back, perhaps killing any fence who refuses to do business with them, or paying off a snitch to lay the blame of something stolen back on a prominent figure in the thieves guild. Alternatively, the character might want to keep everyone else out of it and just take out the leaders of the thieve's guild.

Answer (score 0):

I've GM'd a Lankhmar game for 8 years now.

The old school 2e Lankhmar Thieves Guild supplement is out of print, but it goes deep into the mechanics of how ancient thieves guilds operated. Also what their rules are, various rackets, how to catch freelancers, etc.

I'll provide some of that stuff here in case you don't want to go dig it up:

A "gang" extorts a region by bullying the locals. They may have a rough rank system, but ultimately it's all about status and saving face. Gangs attack anything that might cause their victims to stop fearing them. They're also very "macho", so they have to look tough for one another.

A "thieves guild" is purely focused on making money. Everything is viewed in terms of profit or loss. They have arrangements with the nobility to provide services or outlawed goods (drugs) in return for occasional favors. They also have a network of commoners who protect them and act as informants because the guild members are some of their best customers.

Gangs are *terrified* of thieves guilds because the guild response to any sort of aggression from a gang is to hire professional killers (who don't frighten easily) to remove the gang's leadership.

A "gang" war means groups of guys raiding each other's homes at night, beating up family, burning down businesses, etc. Their ultimate goal is to force the other group to abandon the territory. If that isn't possible they eventually sit down to work out terms (with lots of posturing and threats) or else the winning gang absorbs what remains of the losing gang. There will be collateral damage and innocents getting hurt, but it can't go too far. As soon as the local ruler starts to look weak (especially in the eyes of neighboring countries with their own professional armies) there will be a crackdown. That means enraged knights, bannermen, and hired mercenaries roaming the city putting up notices and hanging anyone caught with a gang sign. Or stuffing them into crows cages to die of dehydration. Remember that this is a "medieval" setting, so displays of brutality are very effective at quelling dissent.

A "guild" war is worse, and usually happens one of two ways.

1. A guild from a foreign city tries to 'move in' on the territory and take control of the underworld (this is just the worst).
2. A charismatic criminal decides to start his own guild because the old one is weak or did something to piss off enough of the cities thieves that he thinks he can get away with it without getting his throat slit.

It takes a lot to make a thieves guild go to war. Angry adventurers killing a few guild thieves for robbing them usually isn't enough. If the party is actively persecuting the guild the answer is to hire a rival adventuring party to take them out. If that fails it's best to hire mercenaries *and* get the local nobility to turn the watch against them and run them out of the city.

If a rival power group is trying to *take* the guilds territory through violence and espionage then the war is very bad. Infiltration is the first concern because secrecy is the guilds first line of defense, and if a rival power group is targeting guild members it implies a security breach. The guild will immediately close ranks and call a meeting to make a list of its assets. Then they send people out to secure these assets and determine who has been compromised. If they have good reason to doubt someone's loyalty that person will be considered a liability and killed as a precaution. There won't be any "gang fights", but people will start disappearing. The guild will set up some stings to draw out members of the rival organization and capture them to torture them for information. Common folk will notice something going on that they can't fully see, and suddenly the city will develop an atmosphere of extreme paranoia. Fences and "third party" criminals without strong guild loyalties will pack up shop and vanish until the matter is "handled". Nobles will distance themselves from the guild to avoid being targeted as "enemy assets" who need to be eliminated to weaken the guilds hold on the city. Unless of course there's a big enough body count that they're obliged to protect the public from collateral damage.

A war between guilds usually ends in genocide. Professional thieves who manage to sneak away are *very* well equipped to come back later and exact revenge. Everyone understands this, so both groups will try to make the purge as complete as possible. This includes sending assassins to hunt down a known guild member who has fled town.

I hope this helps.